# How to change Angular-UI element property with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to have a simple accordion with two buttons at the top: one button that opens every panel and one that collapses them.

I'm trying to use jQuery's `prop` method to alter the `is-open` property on each uib-accordion element, but nothing happens when I click on either button.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionController">
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="openAll()">Open All</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="collapseAll()">Collapse All</button>
    </p>
    <uib-accordion close-others="false">
        <uib-accordion-group class="accordionGroup" ng-repeat="xmlResult in xmlResults" is-open="false">
            <uib-accordion-heading>
                //heading...
            </uib-accordion-heading>
            //content...
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module("ResultsTreeViewer").controller("AccordionController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.openAll = function () {
        $(".accordionGroup").prop("is-open", true);
    };
    $scope.collapseAll = function () {
        $(".accordionGroup").prop("is-open", false);
    }
});
```

I'd love an Angular only solution but that isn't necessary. I just want it to work.

Comment: `is-open` is an [attribute and not a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr#answer-5884994).

Comment: @Stryner Using `attr` doesn't work either. What do you suggest I use?

Comment: When inspecting the element, [it works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/t37uuoju/1/).

Comment: @Stryner I see that it updated the is-open attribute, but it's not opening or closing any of the accordions. I suppose the answer to that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say that don't use `jQuery` with Angular, inside controller.

Rather have `isOpen` variable inside each `accordion` record and then make it `true` & `false` by calling single function `actionAccordion` function(Make sense to have it in angular way).

**Markup**

```
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="actionAccordion(true)">Open All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="actionAccordion(false)">Collapse All</button>
</p>
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
    <uib-accordion-group class="accordionGroup" ng-repeat="xmlResult in xmlResults" 
      is-open="xmlResult.isOpen">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            //heading...
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        //content...
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.actionAccordion = function (flag) {
    angular.forEach($scope.xmlResults, function(xmlResult){
        xmlResults.isOpen = flag;
    })
};
```

Comment: This is as correct as an answer can get for my question because the `is-open` property can only accept an angular object, not a string literal.

Comment: @LCIII yupe.. internally `accordion` directive has `isOpen` variable with it... it toggle whenever he wanted to `show` & `hide`(this toggling process can happen from both side, because accordion binded with `isOpen: '='`)